# Full Calendar wrong time on click event google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I needed to make Google calendars look nice for a client, so I used Fullcalendar and it now looks great, thanks! 
I have one problem though:
When I click on an event, the details display the GMT time. I tried a few things, but I am definitely not a developer, so I need help :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my js code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'my api key',

        events: 'my event',

        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window

            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=600,height=400');
            return false;
            $scope.start = event;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);

        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'my calendar xml link',
               dataType: 'xml',
               data: {

                   start: start.unix(),
                   end: end.unix()
               },
               success: function(doc) {
                   var events = [];
                   $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                       events.push({
                           title: $(this).attr('title'),
                           start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                       });
                   });
                   callback(events);
               }
           });
        }, 
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'my api key',

        events: 'my calendar id',

        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window


            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=600,height=400');
            return false;
            $scope.start = event;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);

        }   

    });

});
```